# How many DNS records are necessary when changing DNS providers?

Tags: dns

I changed DNS provider recently and I am trying to add DNS records to my new provider. However, I am unsure about how many records I should add.

My old nameserver had a whole bunch of auto-created records like "ftp.example.com", "cpanel.example.com", "_carddavs._tcp.example.com", "webdisk.example.com", "autodiscover.example.com", etc etc.

So my question is, can I just add the below **TWO** A records?

@ ---> A Record pointing to my host IP address

www ---> A Record pointing to my host IP address

Any replies would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, but for a simple webserver, yes that is all you need.  I would suggest an MX record for email, and maybe a AAAA record for ipv6.

Answer (score 0):

This question is akin to asking 'how many contacts do I need in my address book'

If you only have one friend, then a single record is all you need. (I'm ignoring the required SOA and NS records)

If you are going to have something talking to ftp.example.com then go ahead and add that record.

If you want to recieve mail on that domain, then you will need at least one MX record.

If you want to host a website at www.example.com then you will need to add a www A record. (or if you want to host a website at notwww.example.com, then add that A record)

Fill your DNS up with whatever you need it to have.

The reason for all of the already included options is that they lead off to revenue generating pages for whoever hosts your domain.